# Extraer datos de un EditText y agregarlos a objeto

Tags: java, android, edittext

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
      ArrayList<Lista_entrada> llibres = new ArrayList<Lista_entrada>();

    // Afegim uns llibres d'exemple.
    llibres.add(new Lista_entrada( "BUHO", "Búho es el nombre común d."));
    llibres.add(new Lista_entrada( "COLIBRÍ", "Los troquilinos"));
```

La duda que tengo es ahora mismo la introduzco directamente.  Pero me gustaría poder extraer los datos de dos `EditText`.

El problema lo tengo porque :

`llibres.add(new Lista_entrada( String, String );` 
( Espera 2 `strings` )

¿Podéis ponerme un ejemplo de como rellenarlo con el contenido de 2 `EditText`?

Comment: Tu objeto Lista_entrada necesita 2 strings simplemente obten los valores de los EditText, ejemplo: new Lista_entrada( EditText1.getText(), EditText2.getText()) @MontseMkd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no entiendo muy bien tu pregunta.

pero imagino que quieres obtener los valores de dos `EditText` ..  y agregarlos al listado.

supongo que solo debes de hacer esto.

define los `EditText`

```
EditText EditText1= findViewById(R.id.EditText1);
EditText EditText2 = findViewById(R.id.EditText2);
```

obtienes los valores de cada `EditText`

```
String text1 = EditText1.getText();
String text2 = EditText2.getText();
```

llenar la lista

```
llibres.add(new Lista_entrada( text1 , text2 );
```

Comment: lo pruebo y te digo! :) es más facil entonces de lo que pensaba! Gracias!!

Comment: No sería necesario el `findViewById(R.id.editText1)`

Comment: lo puedes hacer directo 
llibres.add(new Lista_entrada( EditText1.getText(), EditText2.getText()); 
pero ya depende de ti ;)

Comment: @rencinas, si con ese ejemplo, la respuesta seria mas completa

Answer (score 0):

`llibres` es una lista de objetos `Lista_entrada`

```
 ArrayList<Lista_entrada> llibres = new ArrayList<Lista_entrada>();
```

Si quieres insertar valores de dos `EditText` hacia cada objeto  `Lista_entrada`, obtén los textos de los `TextView` (obviamente debes obtener las referencias de los `EditText` en tu layout mediante `findViewById(R.id.<id EditText>)` )

```
   //Obtiene datos de los EditText.
   String texto1 = EditText1.getText();
   String texto2 = EditText2.getText();
   //Crea objeto con valores de los EditText.    
   Lista_entrada elementoLista = new Lista_entrada( texto1 , texto2 );
   //Agrega elemento a lista. 
   llibres.add(elementoLista);
```

o simplemente agregar los valores directamente

```
   //Crea objeto con valores de los EditText.    
   Lista_entrada elementoLista = new Lista_entrada( EditText1.getText(), EditText2.getText());
   //Agrega elemento a lista. 
   llibres.add(elementoLista);
```